# Configuração de service worker

Tags: javascript, configuração, service-worker

Tem como configurar o codigo abaixo da service worker para ignorar o cache caso a requisição que vem do servidor for 200? Meu service worker tá pegando até rotas que existem e não estão cacheadas e gerando diversos erros na aplicação.

Quando eu unregister a aplicação funciona perfeitamente.

```
var version = '0.8'; //Corrigido o erro de cache
self.addEventListener('install', function (event) {
    event.waitUntil(
        caches.open('v1').then(function (cache) {
            return cache.addAll([
                '/',
                '/css/app.css',
                '/js/app.js',
                '/cache.js',
                '/favicon.ico',
                '/js/gauge.min.js',
                '/manifest.json',
                '/avatar.png',
            ]);
        })
    );
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', function (event) {
    // if (handler) {
    //     event.respondWith(handler(event.request));
    // } else if (router.default && event.request.method === 'GET') {
    //     event.respondWith(router.default(event.request));
    // }
    event.respondWith(
        caches.open('mysite-dynamic').then(function (cache) {
            return cache.match(event.request).then(function (response) {
                if (response) {
                    return response;
                } else {
                    return fetch(event.request).then(function (response) {
                        cache.put(event.request, response.clone());
                        return response;
                    });
                }
            });
        })
    );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

A ideia é criar uma promessa que diz o que acontece quando da notfound ou error retornando a função que adiciona algo especifico algo assim

```
self.addEventListener('install', function (event) {

return Promise.all(
    [
        caches.open(CACHE_VERSIONS.assets)
            .then(
                (cache) => {
                    return cache.addAll(BASE_CACHE_FILES);
                }
            ),
        caches.open(CACHE_VERSIONS.offline)
            .then(
                (cache) => {
                    return cache.addAll(OFFLINE_CACHE_FILES);
                }
            ),
        caches.open(CACHE_VERSIONS.notFound)
            .then(
                (cache) => {
                    return cache.addAll(NOT_FOUND_CACHE_FILES);
                }
            )
    ]
).then(() => {
        return self.skipWaiting();
    });})
```

segue link de como está meu service work está funcionando bem ele consegue identificar a situação do arquivo e direcionar para algo determinado.

clica no link e vai na opção JS
[Exemplo Service Work](https://code.sololearn.com/WkctEQbInkTt)